# Issue with back_url() using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The piece of code I have runs through the array and makes a clickable link of each element

```
foreach($query as $news_item)
{
?>
   <li>
       <a href= <?php echo base_url("pages/view/"); echo $news_item['game_id']; ?> >test</a>
   </li>        
<?php
}
```

I'm attempting to use the baseurl() to return to site url, then direct to the pages/view/ and then a variable of the game_id of the element in the array.

The example above gives me the follow url for the link;

http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0862025/CodeIgniter/index.php/pages/view1

even though, there is clearly a / after view, its completely ignoring it and I've zero idea as to why as I'm still new to php.

Any help would be lovely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it's stripping it out as part of the base_url function. Try this instead

`<a href="<?php echo base_url("pages/view/{$news_item['game_id']}"); ?>">test</a>`

Comment: That works perfectly! Wasn't aware you do do the {} in the middle of strings to include another variable